# How to display a ToolWindow through a funtion call in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extension-methods

Is there a way to display a ToolWindow through a function call? I am aware of the tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138567.aspx, which shows how to provide a ToolWindow through a package and add it to menu, however, I am looking for a way to display a ToolWindow through a function call. Something like this:

```
void ShowToolWindow(){
  ToolWindowPane window = new ToolWindowPane();
  window.Content = myControl();
  frame = window.frame();
  frame.Show();
}
```

Comment: Are you writing an extension for Visual Studio? Or a regular application?

Comment: I am writing a visual studio extension

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you are referring to actually includes the ShowToolWindow function:

```
window = (FirstToolWindow) this.package.FindToolWindow(typeof(FirstToolWindow), 0, true);
if ((null == window) || (null == window.Frame))
{
  throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot create tool window");
}
IVsWindowFrame windowFrame = (IVsWindowFrame)window.Frame;
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(windowFrame.Show());
```